# Is it possible to add a Draggable and DragTarget widget inside the Customized Containers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, drawing, draggable, gesturedetector

Here is the code of Customized Three Containers using ClipPath for obtaining alphabet "A". This Code can also draw inside these three containers. But the drawing can be done in any direction. I want to make this code into drawing from top to bottom inside first container ,when the first drawing done then the second container is activated, after drawing of second Container then the third one to be activated (Tracing Alphabet). I think there should be 3 pairs of Draggable and DragTarget. Drawing is done by using GestureDetector. Is there is any way draw line using Draggable widget, Please respond anyone konws the solution

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([]);
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]).then((_){
    runApp(MyApp());
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Offset> points1 = [];
  List<Offset> points2 = [];
  List<Offset> points3 = [];

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double width  = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double height  = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          points1.clear();
          points2.clear();
          points3.clear();
        },
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      body: SafeArea(
        child:Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.381,
                top:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.560,
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: CPath3(),
                  child: Container(
                    height: height*0.07,
                    width: width*0.18,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanStart: (details){
                        this.setState(() {
                          points3.add(details.localPosition);
                        });
                      },
                      onPanUpdate: (details){
                        this.setState(() {
                          points3.add(details.localPosition);
                        });
                      },
                      onPanEnd: (details){
                        this.setState(() {
                          points3.add(null);
                        });
                      },
                      child: CustomPaint(
                        painter: MyPainter3(points3: points3),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),//THIRD PATH
              Positioned(
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.283,
                // bottom: 0,
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.194,
                //right: 0,
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: CPath1(),
                  child: Container(
                    height: height*0.60,
                    width: width*0.20,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanStart: (details){
                        this.setState(() {
                          points1.add(details.localPosition);
                        });
                      },
                      onPanUpdate: (details){
                        this.setState(() {
                          points1.add(details.localPosition);
                        });
                      },
                      onPanEnd: (details){
                        this.setState(() {
                          points1.add(null);
                        });
                      },
                      child: CustomPaint(
                        painter: MyPainter1(points1: points1),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),//FIRST PATH
              Positioned(
                left:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.467,
                // bottom: 0,
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.194,
                //right: 0,
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: CPath2(),
                  child: Container(
                    height: height*0.60,
                    width: width*0.20,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanStart: (details){
                        this.setState(() {
                          points2.add(details.localPosition);
                        });
                      },
                      onPanUpdate: (details){
                        this.setState(() {
                          points2.add(details.localPosition);
                        });
                      },
                      onPanEnd: (details){
                        this.setState(() {
                          points2.add(null);
                        });
                      },
                      child: CustomPaint(
                        painter: MyPainter2(points2: points2),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),//SECOND PATH
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CPath1 extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(0,size.height);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.2983628,size.height);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width,0);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.7591676,0);
    path_0.lineTo(0,size.height);
    path_0.close();
    return path_0;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    // TODO: implement shouldReclip
    return true;
  }

}
class MyPainter1 extends CustomPainter {
  List<Offset> points1;
  MyPainter1({this.points1});
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
   Paint background = Paint()..color =  Colors.white;
   Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
   canvas.drawRect(rect, background);

   Paint paint = Paint();
   paint.color = Colors.deepPurpleAccent;
   paint.strokeWidth = 70;
   paint.isAntiAlias = true;
   paint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

   for(int x=0;x<points1.length-1;x++)
     {
       if(points1[x] != null && points1[x+1] != null)
       {
         canvas.drawLine(points1[x], points1[x+1], paint);
       }
       else if(points1[x] != null && points1[x+1] == null)
         {

           canvas.drawPoints(ui.PointMode.points,[points1[x]], paint);
         }
     }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }

}

class CPath2 extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(size.width*0.6738603,size.height);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width,size.height);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.1934179,0);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.08001079,0);
    path_0.lineTo(0,size.height*0.1078064);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.6738603,size.height);
    path_0.close();
    return path_0;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    // TODO: implement shouldReclip
    return true;
  }

}
class MyPainter2 extends CustomPainter {
  List<Offset> points2;
  MyPainter2({this.points2});
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint background = Paint()..color =  Colors.white;
    Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, background);

    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.deepPurpleAccent;
    paint.strokeWidth = 70;
    paint.isAntiAlias = true;
    paint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    for(int x=0;x<points2.length-1;x++)
    {
      if(points2[x] != null && points2[x+1] != null)
      {
        canvas.drawLine(points2[x], points2[x+1], paint);
      }
      else if(points2[x] != null && points2[x+1] == null)
      {

        canvas.drawPoints(ui.PointMode.points,[points2[x]], paint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }

}

class CPath3 extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(size.width*0.9108546,0);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.08746101,0);
    path_0.lineTo(0,size.height);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width,size.height*0.9771505);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.9108546,0);
    path_0.close();
    return path_0;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    // TODO: implement shouldReclip
    return true;
  }

}
class MyPainter3 extends CustomPainter {
  List<Offset> points3;
  MyPainter3({this.points3});
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint background = Paint()..color =  Colors.white;
    Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, background);

    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.deepPurpleAccent;
    paint.strokeWidth = 70;
    paint.isAntiAlias = true;
    paint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    for(int x=0;x<points3.length-1;x++)
    {
      if(points3[x] != null && points3[x+1] != null)
      {
        canvas.drawLine(points3[x], points3[x+1], paint);
      }
      else if(points3[x] != null && points3[x+1] == null)
      {

        canvas.drawPoints(ui.PointMode.points,[points3[x]], paint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }

}
```